# Kafka stream to correlate messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to group messages based on a criteria that would come in random order within a time duration?

The messages have different identifiers and the identifiers may need to be stored in memory for correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Kafka is not about grouping messages. Likely you can create a consumer that detects groups in your normal messages stream, and posts the groups it finds as lists of IDs under a different topic.

Then a consumer of that topic can retrieve grouped messages.

Comment: I don't really want to group messages. As the messages have different identifiers, I want to add an identifier to related messages.

Comment: Kafka messages are immutable. You can either consume the incoming stream and publish a new stream, with a group identifier added, or post group -> id mapping separately.

Comment: I want to send the message to another topic. I went through the word count example. Is there any other example or post that would help?

Comment: @las You can use the rg.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer API to send the messages to another topic within the streaming consumer code.

Comment: The word count example also sends the output to another topic.